# Multipolygon support in Lucene .net

Tags: geospatial, lucene.net, nettopologysuite

I am trying to learn lucene .net spatial capabilities .

I want to find if a point exist inside a multi-polygon or not.

From my studies on google, I understand I need to use Net topology suite to describe the multi polygon.

but i am unable to find Lucene.Net.Contrib.Spatial.NTS for the latest version.

Any suggestions (i am using .net core)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this confusion is centered around a couple of things:

### New Lucene Design

Lucene 4.x+ is a completely different design than prior versions. The `Lucene.Net.Contrib` package is no longer part of that design. Instead, there are now [specialized modules](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00013/#libraries) for different functionality. In this case, what you are looking for is the [Lucene.Net.Spatial](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00013/api/spatial/Lucene.Net.Spatial.html) assembly.

### Spatial4n no longer duplicates types

In Spatial4n 0.3.0, `Spatial4n.Core.NTS` included copies of all of the types of `Spatial4n.Core`. This meant that you could not reference both libraries at the same time because they had conflicting type names. It required `Lucene.Net.Contrib.Spatial` to also duplicate types (in `Lucene.Net.Contrib.Spatial.NTS`) in order to access the functionality of NetTopologySuite.

Since Spatial4n 0.4.1, [Spatial4n.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spatial4n.Core/) types are not included in [Spatial4n.Core.NTS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spatial4n.Core.NTS/). Instead `Spatial4n.Core.NTS` references `Spatial4n.Core`.

This means in Lucene.NET 4.8 there is no need to have a separate `Lucene.Net.Spatial.NTS` library that references `Spatial4n.Core.NTS` (and its duplicate type system of `Spatial4n.Core`). However, you can add the NTS functionality to your project by referencing `Spatial4n.Core.NTS` directly.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Spatial4n.Core" Version="0.4.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Spatial4n.Core.NTS" Version="0.4.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

### Examples

As Ron C correctly pointed out, there are some [basic tests](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/Lucene.Net_4_8_0_beta00013/src/Lucene.Net.Tests.Spatial/Prefix/NtsPolygonTest.cs) of NetTopologySuite (NTS) functionality in the Lucene.Net 4.8.0 codebase. But as noted above, you need to reference `Spatial4n.Core.NTS` to access the extensions for NTS.

There are also some additional tests for Spatial4n using NetTopologySuite that can be analyzed.

- [NtsBinaryCodecTest](https://github.com/NightOwl888/Spatial4n/blob/v0.4.1.0/Spatial4n.Tests/io/NtsBinaryCodecTest.cs)
- [NtsWKTReaderShapeParserTest](https://github.com/NightOwl888/Spatial4n/blob/v0.4.1.0/Spatial4n.Tests/io/NtsWKTReaderShapeParserTest.cs)
- [NtsWktShapeParserTest](https://github.com/NightOwl888/Spatial4n/blob/v0.4.1.0/Spatial4n.Tests/io/NtsWktShapeParserTest.cs)
- [NtsGeometryTest](https://github.com/NightOwl888/Spatial4n/blob/v0.4.1.0/Spatial4n.Tests/shape/NtsGeometryTest.cs)

If you need more specific information about the functionality, I suggest you search for the Java examples using the terms "Lucene spatial JTS", "Spatial4j", and "JavaTopologySuite". Since the port is done line-by-line for the most part, the Java examples should be fairly easy to translate to .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the specific spatial features of Lucene.Net yet but perhaps this [NtsPolygonTest](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/master/src/Lucene.Net.Tests.Spatial/Prefix/NtsPolygonTest.cs) will be of help since it appears to be a test of just the type of functionality you are looking for.

I do see that most of the features for spatial live in the [Lucene.Net.Spatial](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/tree/master/src/Lucene.Net.Spatial) namespace (and below).

Also, it looks like the Spatial features use the [Spatial4n nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spatial4n.Core/) which is a port of the Spacial4J java library.